# Is it a good idea to mention crowdsourced projects on an entry-level resume?

Tags: resume, entry-level

I have taken part in quite a few crowdsourced projects for the localization/qa of some apps for big companies (Disney, google, audi). would mentioning these projects in my - sadly poor - resume increase my chances of netting a job?

Comment: Are you looking for localisation work or anything in which localisation would  be relevant

Comment: at this point i'm trying anything. I'd love to find something with a proper advancement perspective, but considering how young I am and the little experience i have i would accept almost anything for the sake of experience.

Comment: Paid localisation projects go to qualified translators, usually academics or teams. If you want to get into that industry, get qualified in it.

Comment: the projects i listed were paid (not too much - 50€ to 150€ per project), if that changes anything.

Comment: List them as work experience then, if you got paid, it's work.

Answer (score 6):

***Absolutely***. As long as you can back up your contributions in some way then it'd be a good idea to include any useful and on-topic experience you've had at other companies.

That type of experience shows willingness to learn and to contribute to projects in your own time. If you've contributed code or indeed language translations it shows off your abilities and where you're currently at professionally.

Comment: It's better than nothing so worth mentioning.

Comment: what is a good way to demonstrate my contribution other than just giving them the finished app? i mean id have about 10 issues reported per project (mostly bad translation and such)

Comment: Provide links of your most proudest contributions which demonstrate different skills you've used on the project.

Comment: also - and i guess that's the most important part - how do i list these projects on my resume?

Comment: Free localisation is a hobby or at best an 'Other interests', particularly if you're not a qualified linguist or translator. I've done several including Firefox browser, I don't even list them. But in the absence of anything else it will help flesh out your resume.

Comment: If you received any feedback, even automated, keep it handy. If nothing else, it shows you are self-motivated and self-teaching.  Sadly, those are in short supply these days.